# Refused to execute inline script with Comodo Trust Seal

Tags: html, javascript

I'm trying to add the Comodo Trust Seal on my site but it gives this error in chrome:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-vhrQsqENchpHihJQOgFTEaBmOiOTI6hAqox4RMB8duY='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

this is comodo code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
  var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.trust-provider.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  TrustLogo("https://ssl.comodo.com/images/seals/sectigo_trust_seal_lg_2x.png", "SECDV", "none");
</script>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you ask Comodo to give you an updated snippet? The correct path security wise is indeed the sha256 hash (see https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_script_integrity.asp) but obviously it needs to be maintained...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is presenting a Content Security Policy header, which defines that default-src is 'none'.

A **None** value means that no external or internal scripts can execute unless a valid ***nonce*** or ***SHA256*** checksum is present.

You could modify the **Content Security Policy** header to allow self-hosted scripts, and in this case, the one from comodo:

```
default-src 'self' *.comodo.com;
```

Another approach is to [whitelist the script using SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108890/whitelisting-inline-script-with-csp-sha-256-in-firefox).